# Flask missing page reload

Tags: python, flask, conda

I'm trying to develop a simple Flask app and I'm facing the problem of missing browser page refresh when source code is updated.

I'm using conda virtual environment and VS Code for script writing on a Mac OSX Monterey Apple Mac mini (M1, 2020).

This is the well known source code I tried (app.py):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

I tried starting the server this way:

1. python app.py
2. flask run
3. flask run --debug
4. flask run --reload
5. flask run --debug --reload

always providing the following environment variables:
export FLASK_APP=app
export FLASK_DEBUG=1

No way I could get the page updated in browser (I also disabled browser cache).

This is the console log:

```
% flask run  
* Serving Flask app 'app'  
* Debug mode: on 
WARNING:    This is a development server. Do not use it in a production    deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.  
* Running on    http://127.0.0.1:5000 Press CTRL+C to quit  
* Restarting with stat  
*    Debugger is active!  
* Debugger PIN: 122-907-708
   127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2024 01:03:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
   127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2024 01:03:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
   127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2024 01:03:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
   127.0.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2024 01:03:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I expected to see two lines like the following to appear as soon as the modified code was saved:

```
 * Detected change in ...
 * Restarting with stat
```

but, as you can see, there's no trace of them in the log.

I also noticed that, updating app.py code via nano utility, VS Code detected the external changes as soon as I saved them, meaning that the listening mechanism is working.

Just so we can exclude a browser problem, I'm using Chrome, but after a source code modification, I opened the page in Safari (first opening in that browser) and Safari shown the old page, so we can exclude any browser cache issue.

Can someone help me to make the server reload the pages when modified (or even to reload them every time they're requested, whether or not modified).

Thank you.

Comment: To be precise, what is the version of `flask`?

Comment: Flask Version:
  2.2.5
----- 
VS Code Version: 
  1.86.1
  Commit: 31c37ee8f63491495ac49e43b8544550fbae4533
  Date: 2024-02-07T09:08:57.920Z
  Electron: 27.2.3
  ElectronBuildId: 26495564
  Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
  Node.js: 18.17.1
  V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
  OS: Darwin arm64 21.6.0